# What are the differences between simple, compound, complex, or compound-complex sentences?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

These two sentences came up in a English Comp class and there was some discussion if the book was correct on whether they were simple, compound, complex, or compound-complex.

> - Whatever pizza Lucy orders is a meal in itself.
> - You can choose whatever crust you prefer and size you prefer.

I feel that the sentences are unnecessarily contrived; but could someone explain how you should properly parse them and define if the sentences are simple, compound, complex or compound-complex?

A simple sentence has one independent clause.
A compound sentence has more than one independent clause.
A complex sentence has one independent clause with one or more dependent clauses.
A compound-complex sentence has more than one independent clause and at least one dependent clause.

Comment: The second sentence is only "unlikely" because in most contexts you'd either discard the first *you prefer* in the interests of brevity, or go the whole hog and repeat the word *whatever*. Other than that, they're just normal English. I don't see any structural similarity between the two sentences. The first is a simple *"A is B"* statement, the second is a two-choice offer - *"You can have A or B"*. What exactly is it you want to know about them?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If they are simple, compound, complex, or compound-complex.

Comment: @qw3n If you an expect any answer to your question, you must first ***rigorously define your terms***, which I note that you have not done. Each of the four things you demand answers about must get its own rigorous and unambiguous definitions. What is a simple sentence? What is a compound sentence? What is a complex sentence? What is a compound-complex sentence? Explain all that, and in detail, and clearly, and without overlap, or we cannot answer you.

Comment: @tchrist I have defined my terms.  However, I felt that those terms were pretty standard as far as grammar goes. Do I also need to define clause?

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes, in syntactic analysis, those 4 terms are commonly used, but most people here probably don’t know them, so it is good to spell them out exactly. And no, don’t worry about clauses, since people understand a clause has a subject and verb.

Comment: @qw3n: The first sentence is *simple* (as I said, structurally, it's just *"A is B"*). For the second sentence, assuming you analyse *A and/or B* as a single unit, is also simple. But the underlying sentence before deletion of repeated elements is *"You can choose whatever crust you prefer and **you can choose whatever** size you prefer"*, which is arguably *compound*, since effectively "and" separates two independent clauses. I think this is one of those cases where such classification doesn't necessarily lead to enlightenment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are simple sentences. They have a single subject and a single predicate.

In the first sentence the noun clause [ *Whatever pizza Lucy orders* ] is the subject: and [ *is a meal in itself* ] is the predicate, in this case a complement.

In the second sentence [ *You* ] is the subject and [ *can choose whatever crust you prefer and size you prefer* ] is the predicate, containing the verb and the object noun clause [ *whatever crust you prefer and size you prefer* ].

Answer (score 0):

In the simple sentence, only one subject and one verb
In the compound sentence, two complete clauses and co-ordinate conjugation uses.
In the complex sentence, the one complete clause and subordinate conjugation uses

Comment: Are those three 'complete sentences'?